# New single page app needs to authenticate to legacy app using Shibboleth

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application, openid-connect, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I am creating a new React SPA. Users of a legacy app need be able to use the new app without re-authenticating. So I need to support SSO.

It's important to note that it is also required that users of other (currently unspecified) apps should also be able to use the new app without re-authenticating, so whatever approach I take needs to be sufficiently decoupled to potentially allow this.

The legacy app supports authentication via Shibboleth, the new app currently has no authentication method, but uses JWT for authorisation.

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience of such a scenario? It seems to me that I probably need to be create an OAuth2 authorisation server for the new app to talk to and I need to somehow bring Shibboleth into the mix for the authentication, maybe with the authorisation service acting as a Shibboleth Service Provider. Googling around hasn't revealed much useful info.

Is what I've described along the right lines? I know it's very high level and woolly, but I'm really not sure of the approach to take. Any advice, information or experience in this area would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

**GOALS**

It's a little bit of a subjective question, but the main goals are usually as follows:

- Focus on building your UI and API security in a future facing manner
- Also provide good Login Usability
- Also deliver on non functional requirements such as availability / reliability

**AUTHORIZATION SERVER**

On the first point, the modern option is to integrate UIs and APIs with an Authorization Server - perhaps as in [My Tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/). Your architecture is then good, but the migration is not trivial.

**FEDERATING TO SHIBBOLETH**

The Authorization Server can then redirect to Shibboleth and talk SAML2.0 to achieve Single Sign On, as you suggest. It is a complex solution though, and may be a backwards step in some ways.

**AVAILABILITY**

This is usually a big concern, and most companies use a cloud provider such as Azure / AWS due to its high availability / low maintenance / low cost. Would this be a better option for you?